# Assembly vs C executable size

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, executable

I wrote two equivalent programs in C and x86 assembly:

```
.386
.model small
INCLUDELIB MSVCRT
EXTRN _printf:NEAR
.data
msg db "Hello World", 10, 0
.code
main PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    lea eax, msg
    push eax
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
main ENDP
END

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the assembly one with:
`ml hello.asm /link /ENTRY:main /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`

And the C one with:
`cl /O1 /MD hello.c`

The /O1 switch is supposed to minimize space and the /MD switch links with MSVCRT.LIB rather than LIBCMT (which is the same thing in my assembly program).

However, when I examine the actual executables the C one is actually twice the size of the assembly one:

```
2014-02-08  10:48 AM             3,072 hello.exe
2014-02-08  10:53 AM             6,144 hello_c.exe
```

Doing a `DUMPBIN /DISASM` on both shows that the assembly one only generates the exact instructions I specified whereas the C one generates several hundred times more...

Does anyone have an explanation as to why an optimizing compiler that was asked to minimize space still produces worse results than an assembly program?

Comment: Out of curiosity - did the assembly "Hello world" actually work?

Comment: You didn't say what tool you're using. Visual Studio adds a bunch of code for stack probes and security features and probably some boilerplate that can't be removed even if it isn't used. There is probably also some wasted space for the static data segment.

Comment: I wouldn't call the a debug version "bloated", but @rohitsan probably has the answer -- the C version includes debug info that the assembler version does not.

Comment: I was wrong.  It was not the debug build.  I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291585 debugging is only enabled when you specify the /Z7 switch on the compiler. And yes, I am using Visual Studio

Comment: Try maximizing your optimizations and recompiling.  That might get rid of a lot of the "unnecessary" assembly language instructions.  Optimizing for size has not worked out too well for me in the past.

Comment: I don't know Windows asm but it looks to me that in your `asm` snippet you explicitly set the ABI to 32 bit, that `.386` looks like a directive for 32 bit code: what is the target platform used when you compile your `C` snippet ? It could be a 64 bit target ?

Comment: You know, you could put the hello_c.o file through a disassembler and see exactly what it contains...

Comment: The assembly program is just invalid, it uses printf() without the CRT being initialized.  Invalid code is always smaller.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually, invalid code can also be bigger ;-)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, yes it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its because of the extra boilerplate code added by the C runtime. It has to setup for **atexit**, command line arguments, etc. If you're really curious, disassemble them with the free demo version of IDA Pro (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml)

Comment: Yes, C as language makes many promises for the time that main() runs that no compiler can actually check if they need to be kept. And those promises don't come cheap.